# Return NSString which is set from inside a block

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, block, cllocation

I have a method which looks like this:

```
-(NSString *)getCityFromLocation:(CLLocation *)location {

    __block NSString *city;

    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation: location completionHandler:
     ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

         //Get address
         CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

         city = [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"City"];

         NSLog(@"city 1: %@", city);

     }];

    return city;
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
NSString *city = [self getCityFromLocation:currentLocation];

NSLog(@"city 2: %@", city);
```

In NSLog, I get:

```
city 2: (null)
city 1: London
```

The problem is obvious - it's returning before it's ran the block. How can i get this to work as intended, where it can return the value produced by the block?

Comment: For getting work as you want, you need to implement custom delegate, create a class having this code and a custom delegate which will call delegate function on completion which will return you city. Hope this helps you..

Comment: Would I be able to run this without running it in a block? It's highly inconvenient to do it this way.

Comment: Whats wrong in creating delegates, all default classes uses delegates, they are best way to handle and implement.

Answer (score 1):

Intially you have asssign completion block to `reverseGeocodeLocation`. But It doesn't call at that time. It will call when `reverse Geocode process get complete`. But  `city` get return immediately. That's why you get like this.

You can solve by assign it to local property. When completion block get executed . So code should be.

```
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation: location completionHandler:
     ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

         //Get address
         CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

         self.city = [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"City"];

     }];
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating block inside `getCityFromLocation`, make `getCityFromLocation` as a block (I mean Callback methods).

```
typedef void (^Callback)(BOOL isSuccess, id object);

-(void)getCityFromLocation:(Callback)iCallback
{
    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation: location completionHandler:
        ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

       //Get address
       CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

       city = [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"City"];

      NSLog(@"city 1: %@", city);
      iCallback(YES,city);

   }];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous methods, such as `reverseGeocodeLocation:` you have used here, are normally that for a very good reason - they take time to complete. In that light you should first consider your design and determine whether you really should be trying to use an asynchronous method in a synchronous manner.

If you do decide you need to do this one solution is to use a semaphore. Before the call to `reverseGeocodeLocation:` create a semaphore with `dispatch_semaphore_create` (part of GCD, in section 3 of the manual). Then within your block you use `dispatch_semaphore_signal` to indicate that the string is ready, and outside your block `dispatch_semaphore_wait` to block until the string is ready.

Your code modified to do this, *typed directly into the answer and not executed*:

```
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>

-(NSString *)getCityFromLocation:(CLLocation *)location
{

   __block NSString *city;

   dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

   CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

   [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation: location completionHandler:
      ^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
      {
         //Get address
         CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

         city = [placemark.addressDictionary objectForKey:@"City"];
         dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema); // string is ready
      }
   ];

   dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER); // wait for string
   dispatch_release(sema); // if you are using ARC & 10.8 this is NOT needed
   return city;
}
```

But seriously, consider carefully whether this is what you should be doing.

HTH.

Comment: Does this now becomw synchronous operation?

Comment: Would it be possible to use a semaphore here and then contain the whole thing in a background thread? Would it still move onto my background thread, in that instance?

Comment: @user523234 - It becomes *effectively* synchronous from the point of view of the caller of `getCityFromLocation:`. Whatever thread the call to the method is made on will block until the completion handler signals the semaphore, but `reverseGeocodeLocation:` will still be executed on another thread. *[Note: Don't worry about this unless it happens, but it is possible, but unlikely, that `reverseGeocodeLocation:` isn't preformed on a separate thread at all in which case the above solution will just deadlock at the wait. If this is the case you cannot make a "synchronous" version at all.]*

Comment: @Andrew - You can call `getCityLocation:` from any thread and that thread will block until the completion handler signals the semaphore.